# How can I remove duplicates in the query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to remove duplicates as I would like to show just one name in the column 'EnterpriseId' and in this with the highest value (1300 in this case). So basically if I have a same name for a globalofferingleadnm and for a managernm I'd like to get just one value for the globalofferingleadnm removing the managernm.

This is for SQL

```
-- Set Variables
Declare @M1 as INT
Declare @M2 as INT

Set @M1 = '1300'
Set @M2 = '949'

Select
a.globalofferingleadnm as 'EnterpriseID',
Case
When a.GlobalOfferingLeadNm = a.GlobalOfferingLeadNm then  @M1 end as 'FlairID'

from Offering_vw a

where a.OfferingClassNm <> 'Asset Group'
GROUP BY
a.GlobalOfferingLeadNm

UNION

select
a.ManagerNm as 'EnterpriseID',
Case
When a.ManagerNm = a.ManagerNm then @M2 end as 'FlairID'

from Offering_vw a
where a.ManagerNm <> a.GlobalOfferingLeadNm AND a.OfferingClassNm <> 'Asset Group'
Group By
a.ManagerNm
```

If the name is repeated by globalofferingleadnm and managernm, I'd like to get just the globalofferingleadnm and removing the managernm.

Comment: EnterpriseID            Flair ID
a.j.gupta                    949
a.j.gupta                  1300
a.mcintyre            949
aamer.a.chaudhry    949
aaron.g.millstone    949
abhijit.kabra            949
abhishek.m.mishra     949
abigail.h.hart            949
abigail.l.terrill            949

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are really looking to do a join on the two queries, rather than a UNION. You want to only show a single row per EnterpriseID yes?

There may be more elegant solutions that combine both queries in one, but you can always keep them separate and perform some form of join in order to get your results.

In this case I have tried a full outer join, since it seems that there may be a row in either of the two queries.

(note: without your DDL and a SQL Server database, I can't test this)

```
with q1 as(
  Select
  a.globalofferingleadnm as 'EnterpriseID',
  Case
  When a.GlobalOfferingLeadNm = a.GlobalOfferingLeadNm then  @M1 end as 'FlairID'

  from Offering_vw a

  where a.OfferingClassNm <> 'Asset Group'
  GROUP BY
  a.GlobalOfferingLeadNm
),
q2 as(
  select
  a.ManagerNm as 'EnterpriseID',
  Case
  When a.ManagerNm = a.ManagerNm then @M2 end as 'FlairID'

  from Offering_vw a
  where a.ManagerNm <> a.GlobalOfferingLeadNm AND a.OfferingClassNm <> 'Asset Group'
  Group By
  a.ManagerNm
)
select coalesce(q1.EnterpriseID, q2.EnterpriseID) as 'EnterpriseID',
       case when q1.EnterpriseID is not null then q1.'FlairID' else q2.'FlairID' end as 'FlairID'
  from q1 full outer join q2 on q1.'EnterpriseID' = q2.'EnterpriseID';
```

This approach uses a `WITH` clause to make it easier to treat your two queries as if they were tables, for convenience, as q1 and q2.

Then q1 and q2 are joined with a full outer join--there will be a row, regardless of which source it came from.

The `coalesce` is needed because it is possible for one of the two `EnterpriseID` keys to be null, because of the full outer join.

Finally, the `case` statement is where the preferred source of `FlairID` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this case you need to derive temp tables and then combine them where the initial results don't exist, since globalofferingleadnm takes precedence. Also, not entirely certain you need those case statements.

```
-- Set Variables
Declare @M1 as INT
Declare @M2 as INT

Set @M1 = '1300'
Set @M2 = '949'

Select
    a.globalofferingleadnm as 'EnterpriseID',
    @M1 'FlairID'

into
    #temp 1

from
    Offering_vw a

where
    a.OfferingClassNm <> 'Asset Group'

GROUP BY
    a.GlobalOfferingLeadNm
;

select
    a.ManagerNm as 'EnterpriseID',
    @M2 'FlairID'

into
    #temp2

from
    Offering_vw a

where
    a.ManagerNm <> a.GlobalOfferingLeadNm AND a.OfferingClassNm <> 'Asset Group'

Group By
    a.ManagerNm
;

insert into
    #temp1

select
    EnterpriseID
    ,FlairID

from
    #temp2 A

where
    exists
        (select 1

        from
            #temp1 B

        where
            A.EnterpriseID <> B.EnterpriseID)
;

select *

from
    #temp1
;
```